# How to sort Django ManyToManyField By middle table's id?

Tags: python, django

Django version: 1.7.9
python version: 2.7.6
Django Models:

```
class VideoList(models.Model):
    playbill_list_set = OrderedManyToManyField(
        "self",
        related_name="video_list_playbill+",
        symmetrical=False,
        verbose_name=u"related videos",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    class Meta:
        db_table = "videolist"
```

Then I syncdb, there is a new table named `videolist_playbill_list_set`.
It's a middle table, and the table's construction is:

[image]

My sort code like these：

```
result = make_order(self.playbill_milist_set).all().order_by('id')
```

unfortunately，the result sorted by `to_video_list_id` in middle table,
I wanna sort by `id` in middle table, what I should do?

Comment: This would not really be clear semantically. You have a `QuerySet` of `VideoList` instances each of which can have multiple related entries in the mid table. How to tell which of these entries should be the one relevant for the sorting? You might want to query the mid table directly.